# Android studio: add comments to read-only files

Tags: android-studio, ide, comments, jetbrains-ide, code-documentation

I need to add some comments in a read-only file opened by Android Studio, for personal documentation purposes. Obviously, I can't use normal comments. Do you know if the editor have some functionality to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8351-code-comments) that solves my problem.